# Constraint o trigger mayores de 18 SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Necesito comprobar al añadir un "votante" en la base de datos si es mayor de 18 años, lo he intentado con un constraint y un check, pero no admite funciones para la fecha actual ¿Qué otras opciones hay?

```
ALTER TABLE votantes
ADD CONSTRAINT cns_mayor18 CHECK (YEAR(now()) - YEAR(fechanac) >= 18);
```

Comment: Como comentario quería decirte que tengas cuidado con esa condición. Solo con tener los años no sería condición suficiente para validar la entrada. Por ejemplo si la `fechaNacimiento = "03/10/1999"` y la `fechaActual = "02/10/2017"` el resultado por año sería 18 (2017-1999), pero en edad sería 17 (le falta 1 día para cumplir 18). Por tal razón deberías comparar fechas completas. No sé si me explico.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MariaDB usas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay por lo menos 3 problemas con tu solución actual:

#### 1. CHECK constraint no hace nada en la mayoría de las versiones actuales

En todas las versiones de MySQL, así como todas las versiones de MariaDB anteriores a 10.2.1, los CHECK constraints no hacen nada. La sintaxis existe, pero, literalmente, no hace nada.

[Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ***ignored*** by all storage engines.

traducido (más o menos):

> La claúsula `CHECK` es analizada, pero ***ignorada*** por todos los motores de almacenamiento.

#### 2. CHECK constraint solo acepta funciones determinísticas

A partir de MariaDB 10.2.1, [finalmente se podrán usar los CHECK constraints como las demás bases de datos](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/constraint/).  Pero aún así, hay 2 problemas:

1. MariaDB 10.2 aún está en BETA.
2. Los CHECK constraints solo aceptan funciones determinísticas, por lo que no puedes usar funciones como `NOW()`, ni `CURDATE()`.

#### 3. La lógica no es correcta

Como bien comentó Pablo Claus, aún si el CHECK constraint aceptara y usara tu expresión correctamente, la lógica que tienes no es correcta, porque no toma en cuenta el mes y el día, sino solamente el año.

Para obtener la edad de una persona a partir de una fecha de nacimiento, la forma correcta de hacerlo es de esta manera:

```
timestampdiff(year, fechanac, now())
```

#### Solución

Por las razones mencionadas arriba, en tu caso, me parece que la única solución correcta es de usar triggers para efectuar la validación. Aquí te dejo un modelo de cómo hacerlo:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure sp_check_cns_mayor18(in fechanac date)
begin
  if timestampdiff(year, fechanac, now()) < 18 then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Votante debe tener 18 años o más.';
  end if;
end
$$

create trigger instrg_check_cns_mayor18
before insert on votantes
for each row
begin
  call sp_check_cns_mayor18(new.fechanac);
end
$$

create trigger updtrg_check_cns_mayor18
before update on votantes
for each row
begin
  call sp_check_cns_mayor18(new.fechanac);
end
$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Gracias por la mención sstan ;)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `CURDATE()` en vez de `NOW()`:

```
ALTER TABLE votantes
ADD CONSTRAINT cns_mayor18 CHECK ((YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fechanac)) >= 18);
```